# Is it possible to load coordinates from MySQL DB and display as markers in Android Google Maps

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using Android Studio to develop an application which provides information where the crime has been committed and XAMPP Server. I just finished loading the Google Map and now I wanted to load the coordinates (Lat & Long) from MySQL Database and display it as markers in my Map View. I followed the tutorial from androidhive.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Can someone please provides me some tutorials or references to this issue.
I badly need some help to finished my project because it is a requirement in my thesis course. Thanks in advance.

HERE'S MY MAP ACTIVITY CODE:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        // Create button
        Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_home);
        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MapActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

            // Showing / hiding your current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming controls
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            // Enable / Disable my location button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            double latitude = 14.5954076;
            double longitude = 120.9883922;


                // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
                if (i == 9) {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                    randomLocation[1])).zoom(16).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }

                // Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the map.
                googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                                .add(new LatLng(14.596046, 120.989171))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.596155, 120.988686))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.595890, 120.988627))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.595991, 120.988074))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.595724, 120.988015))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.596151, 120.986254))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.595351, 120.986125))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.595162, 120.987067))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.595060, 120.987289))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.594383, 120.988190))
                                .add(new LatLng(14.596052, 120.989169))
                );
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    /**
     * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
     */
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                100 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }

}
```

AND MY XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_map" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_home"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_home"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JSON Parser (for HTTP Client Request):

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fetch coordinates from you MySQL Db so you have to make a network connection to fetch data. To create a network connection there are two ways

1. [Choose you HttpClient and perform network request yourself](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#http-client)
2. [Use any library for network connection(Volley)](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/simple.html#simple)

Now assuming that you have data or coordinates now then call the method
[MapFragment.getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallBack)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback))

Now one the map is ready you will receive the object of GoogleMap on which you can then add markers. i.e.

```
@Override
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Marker"));
```

}

Comment: Actually I am using JSON Parser for HTTP Client.
I am able to retrieve values from My MySQL Database in some activity.

Now, I don't know how to retrieve the data (lat & long) from my database to my google map view. I wanted to load markers from that data in my google map view.

Comment: as I already said once you get lat & long values in your activity then call getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) on you MapView or MapFragment and in onMapReady(GoogleMap map) as You are having a   map object you can add markers to it wrapped in LatLng object using the method map.addMarker(new LatLng(lat,long)

Comment: Any good example or tutorial?
Beginner for android dev. here. Please.

Comment: First read about markers at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker then you can try sample provideved by google at : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/code-samples

Comment: Thanks for response.
I just finished this module (loading coordinates from mysql db to google map views). My target now is how I save GPS coordinate to mysql database or using the Embedded GPS Coordinates of captured images by device camera then save this coordinates to mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(BROOKLYN_BRIDGE)
            .title("First Pit Stop")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

for reference use [link](http://javapapers.com/android/markersgoogle-maps-android-api-v2/)

Comment: Data (Lat & Long) from MySQL Database?

Comment: You need to create http connection and also write the suitable web-service which will fetch the lat and long from MYSQl db and you need to parse it with json

Comment: Any good example or tutorial?
Beginner for android dev. here. Please.